# How to remove an index column from a derived dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe whose columns are derived from summary statistics of a data set. During the process it seems an index column is created that I can't get rid of. I describe the problem in detail in the screenshots below. Can you tell how to remove the seemingly index Financial Year without exporting the dataframe to Excel?

[image]

[image]

I should also note that attempt to drop index at the beginning doesn't work either as shown below

[image]

Comment: add an index col when reading your data like :  `pd.read_excel(..., index_col=0)`

Comment: pandas dataframe always have an Index column in one way or another, - only while exporting data to excel/csv or similar, you can command do not export the index column.
`df.to_excel("filename.xlsx", index=False)`

Comment: Sorry I guess I wasn't clear. I mean to ask how to remove the Financial Year column at the beginning without having to export it to Excel. Treating it as either index or a normal column doesn't seem to work for me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the reset_index() method. More in: https://datagy.io/pandas-drop-index-column/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).